# etale cohomology of tori

Tags: algebraic-groups, group-cohomology, etale-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field.
Let $A$ be a strictly henselian local ring which is a $k$-algebra.
Let $T$ a torus over $k((t))$.
Can we compute $H^{1}(A((t)),T)$?

Comment: What do you mean by "compute" with such abstract $T$?  If $A$ has nasty singularities (or even just 2 minimal primes), what kind of answer do you want for $T=\mathbf{G}_m$, for example?